# EMV Static Data Authentication

Tags: authentication, smartcard, apdu, emv, mastercard

In EMV book v4.3 2 page 49 states

> If all of the above steps were executed successfully, SDA was successful. The Data Authentication Code recovered in Table 7 shall be stored in tag '9F45'.

How do I store the Data Authentication Code recovered in tag 9F45

So far I am stuck at this stage, the only thing I have come up is I have to issue a PUT DATA command APDU.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If all of the above steps were executed successfully, SDA was successful. The Data Authentication Code recovered in Table 7 shall be stored in tag '9F45'.

This does not mean that you should store the recovered data authentication code on the card (so no need for any APDU). Instead, it means that you should store the DAC in the data element 9F45 on your reader (POS terminal) for further processing (you will eventually have to send that to the acquirer for clearing the transaction).